# Is it true that in the battle of Mahabharata, the Son of Lord Krishna fought from the Kaurava side?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, kurukshetra, kauravas

I had a discussion with a teacher of mine and he told me that back in his college days, while they were watching Mahabharata, a friend of him said that The son of Lord Krishna also fought in the battle of Mahabharata and that too from the Kaurava's Side. So, I grew curious and posted this.

Comment: Is this Q applies to all the sons of Krishna or only famous sons...?

Comment: Which son? Krishna has many sons such as Pradyumna or Samba... Please specify the name of Krishna’s son you are referring to...