# How many son(s) and daughter(s) did Lord Krishna had?

Tags: krishna

I found a comment in following question

> [Is it true that in the battle of Mahabharata, the Son of Lord Krishna
>   fought from the Kaurava side?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29393/is-it-true-that-in-the-battle-of-mahabharata-the-son-of-lord-krishna-fought-fro)

in that there is comment that is asking for specification of Son name. I think he has only one son (Pradyumna), so my question is How many son(s) and daughter(s) did Lord Krishna had? Name them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know Krishna had eighty sons from His eight principal wives Rukmini, Satyabhama, Jambavati, Nagnajiti, Kalindi, Madra, Mitravinda and Bhadra:

> The first son of Queen Rukmiṇī was Pradyumna, and also born of her were Cārudeṣṇa, Sudeṣṇa and the powerful Cārudeha, along with Sucāru, Cārugupta, Bhadracāru, Cārucandra, Vicāru and Cāru, the tenth. None of these sons of Lord Hari was less than his father. The ten sons of Satyabhāmā were Bhānu, Subhānu, Svarbhānu, Prabhānu, Bhānumān, Candrabhānu, Bṛhadbhānu, Atibhānu (the eighth), Śrībhānu and Pratibhānu.Sāmba, Sumitra, Purujit, Śatajit, Sahasrajit, Vijaya, Citraketu, Vasumān, Draviḍa and Kratu were the sons of Jāmbavatī. These ten, headed by Sāmba, were their father’s favorites. The sons of Nāgnajitī were Vīra, Candra, Aśvasena, Citragu, Vegavān, Vṛṣa, Āma, Śaṅku, Vasu and the opulent Kunti. Śruta, Kavi, Vṛṣa, Vīra, Subāhu, Bhadra, Śānti, Darśa and Pūrṇamāsa were sons of Kālindī. Her youngest son was Somaka. Mādrā’s sons were Praghoṣa, Gātravān, Siṁha, Bala, Prabala, Ūrdhaga, Mahāśakti, Saha, Oja and Aparājita. Mitravindā’s sons were Vṛka, Harṣa, Anila, Gṛdhra, Vardhana, Unnāda, Mahāṁsa, Pāvana, Vahni and Kṣudhi. Saṅgrāmajit, Bṛhatsena, Śūra, Praharaṇa, Arijit, Jaya and Subhadra were the sons of Bhadrā, together with Vāma, Āyur and Satyaka. (Srimad Bhagavatam 10.61.11-17)

I don't know whether He had daughters.